# ora 00942 error: table or view does not exist

Tags: sqlplus

```
Select lname, fname, title as "Book Title" 
from books join line
on books.bookid = book_author.bookid
join author
on author.authorid = book_author.authorid;
```

It keeps saying the table or view does not exist but when I do select * from books; it does show me the table.

Comment: So then it's either `line`, `author`, or `book_author` that doesn't exist.

Comment: Add "join book_author"

Comment: got it. but now it's saying: invalid table name,  but it's not

Comment: SQL> select * from tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
AUTHOR                         TABLE
BOOKS                          TABLE
BOOK_AUTHOR                    TABLE
BOOK_CUSTOMER                  TABLE
BOOK_ORDER                     TABLE
CHANNEL                        TABLE
COURSE                         TABLE
COURSE_SECTION                 TABLE
ENROLLMENT                     TABLE
FACULTY                        TABLE
ORDER_ITEMS                    TABLE

Answer (score 0):

```
Select author.lname, author.fname, books.title as "Book Title" 
from books join book_author --line
on books.bookid = book_author.bookid
join author
on author.authorid = book_author.authorid;
```

`line` has been commented. it should be `book_author` instead. Also included the table-names before the column names in the `select` clause